# How to make a double select sql

Tags: php, sql

I'd like to do a double select with a single query. I searched a lot but i didn't find a solution suitable for me.

This is the code that i have:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM products p
INNER JOIN products_lang pl ON p.id_product = pl.id_product
WHERE pl.id_lang = ? AND p.sold = ? AND p.featured = ?
ORDER BY p.date_insert DESC,p.id_product DESC
LIMIT 10');
$stmt->execute(1,0,1);
$rows_feat = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM products p
INNER JOIN products_lang pl ON p.id_product = pl.id_product
WHERE pl.id_lang = ? AND p.sold = ?
ORDER BY p.date_insert DESC,p.id_product DESC
LIMIT 10');
$stmt->execute(1,0);
$rows_last = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Can i do it i one single query with results like this? Is it possible?

```
$rows['feat'] = Array
$rows['last'] = Array
```

Thanks

Comment: UNION ALL the two SELECT's.

Comment: Now you fetch the 10 latest featured products and the 10 latest products of any kind (featured and not featured). How do you want to combine that exactly? Do you want to get duplicate products?

Comment: The queries do not differ much. If you alter the condition to `AND (? OR p.featured = ?)` you could set the 1st parameter here true/false. Then you need to prepare once and execute twice with different params which is a performance improvement and less code redundance.

Comment: Another approach could be a stored routine generating 2 result sets.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález it doesn't matter for now

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone i'll consider the first solution. Thanks

Comment: It does matter since you would only have to change featured true/false of your first query if you do not want duplicates.

Comment: Or since there is a limit of 10 it would also work to use a UNION and chunk the result array as long as you get all 20 results. Named parameters would make sense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that:

- A recent featured product can show up in both queries.
- You may expect less than 10 products.

… I think the most straightforward way to save a database round-trip is a good old union. If you're actually using `SELECT *` then getting the final order gets tricky because you'll have duplicate column names:

```
(
    SELECT 'feat' AS type_,
    p.date_insert AS sort_date_, p.id_product AS sort_id_
    p.*, pl.*
    FROM products p
    INNER JOIN products_lang pl ON p.id_product = pl.id_product
    WHERE pl.id_lang = ? AND p.sold = ? AND p.featured = ?
    ORDER BY p.date_insert DESC, p.id_product DESC
    LIMIT 10
) UNION ALL (
    SELECT 'last' AS type_,
    p.date_insert AS sort_date_, p.id_product AS sort_id_
    p.*, pl.*
    FROM products p
    INNER JOIN products_lang pl ON p.id_product = pl.id_product
    WHERE pl.id_lang = ? AND p.sold = ?
    ORDER BY p.date_insert DESC,p.id_product DESC
    LIMIT 10
)
ORDER BY type_, sort_date_ DESC, sort_id_ DESC
```

You then need to discard or ignore the auxiliary columns in the result-set.

I suggest you try and benchmark both alternatives with a large dataset to ensure this is actually faster.